# backbone and bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, datepicker

I have a rails app, and I'm trying to add some interactive content tom my views. So I have a bootstrap-datepicker-rails gem for datepicker and backbone.js for data handling. But when I try to listen to 'changeDate' event of datepicker, I get some errors. Hooking event in a view doesn't work at all, the method just doesn't get called:

```
events: 
  'changeDate #dpstart': 'tryit'

tryit: ->
  console.log(this)
  this
```

When I try to catch the event in my router, I can't get access to my collections:

```
initialize: ->
    @datepicker = $('#dpstart').datepicker({
      "format": "yyyy-mm-dd",
      "weekStart": 1,
      "autoclose": true
      })       
    @datepicker.on('changeDate', @refetch, this)
```

This way it produces an error, because it can't get **this** context, and

```
initialize: ->
    @datepicker = $('#dpstart').datepicker({
      "format": "yyyy-mm-dd",
      "weekStart": 1,
      "autoclose": true
      })       
    @datepicker.on('changeDate', @refetch)
```

this way is working fine, but in @refetch I don't get backbone context so can't get access to the models. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Either bind the context yourself with [this](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) (as you have underscore or lowdash). Or use [this method](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) from Backbone to do your bindings (better).

About why the first one doesn't get called, make sure what is returned by the datepicker method is the jQuery element you're binding it to ($('#dpstart')). I don't think so, so you're basically listening to the wrong thing I assume.

Comment: The ListenTo() method looked just like perfect match, but it produces just the same error as in my second code piece. Now gonna try the first method you suggested. =(

Comment: I'm still really puzzled about the second piece of code though. Could you paste the exact error? @TimurMinulin

Comment: Of course. Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Managers> has no method 'apply' - where Managers is my router. 
        this.listenTo(@datepicker, 'changeDate', @tryit) - is the event hook I used.

Comment: It seems your "@refetch" is not a function. That said, I don't know how the 3rd piece of code works then :O. I don't know ror, but could you try replacing "@refetch" by this.refetch if refetch is a method of your Router?

Comment: it's coffeescript. Actually, @refetch is translated into this.refetch, so that's not the point. Here's the source on client side `return this.listenTo(this.datepicker, 'changeDate', this.tryit);`

Comment: `this.listenTo(this.datepicker, 'changeDate', this.tryit);` Aren't you mixing your objects? From what I understood, you did that in your router and tryit is a method of your view, ain't it? If not, could you please post the code of both of those classes?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/krnXuXDV - here's original coffeescript code, pretty clear. I can provide complete JS from client side if you want, but I still think coffeescript is much better to read.

Comment: Can't figure anything wrong with this code. Though your error still bugs me. `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Managers> has no method 'apply'` this would only happen if you try to do `this.apply()` while it should do `this.tryit.apply()`...

Comment: This happens only when I try to hook this handler via backbone object. When I hook the method without passing **this**, everything works fine, but the context is the jQuery datepicker element.

Comment: I guess it was the same binding the context with underscore ? :/

Comment: well, I didn't try the underscore method, because I just don't understand, how does it help. If I'm right, backbone's own `listenTo` does just the same. If you drop some code, I can try it.

Comment: Yeah listenTo proxies .on(name, callback, context) with a bunch of internal mechanisms. I really can't get why adding a context makes it bug... As a last attempt, maybe post more of your code, I'll dig into it when I have some free time if you wish.

Comment: There's no code left to post, really. I didn't post the index function, there's nothing right now - I just want to figure out how to use backbone.

Comment: Could you in fact link a pastebin with your the compiled code (to js then)?